# Thousand Eyes Integration With PagerDuty Service Unavailable

Tags: service, devops, integration, alert, pagerduty

Logging into ***ThousandEyes*** & navigating to **Alerts** -> **Alert Rules** -> (Select Alert Rule) -> Click on **Notifications** Tab & then **Edit Integrations** brings you to a pop up window to Select or **Add New Integration**.

Selecting **Add New Integration** -> **Type: PagerDuty** then **Add New PagerDuty Service** brings you to your PagerDuty Login Page. Once logged in you have the option to select an existing PagerDuty Service to integrate with ThousandEyes.

However in my case, some services are available & some are not. When comparing 1 service that isn't available to 1 that is in PagerDuty there's no significant difference that I can see.

I would like to select a PagerDuty Service for Integration that is in the list but greyed out. See screenshots.

I wonder if anyone else has the same issue & if so how can you resolve it?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the PagerDuty Service Settings "Enable Alerts" Button needs to be clicked for the thousandeyes integration to work properly (not be greyed out).

[image]